# Alternative to Timestamp for use with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm looking for an alternative for the UNIX Timestap for a use with PHP and MySQL, because i want to start a project, but i have no idea how to store past and future dates. Are there easy-to-use alternatives (the "timestamps" must be calculated with PHP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime() field type and use NOW() etc you can then take advantage of the mysql built in datediff functions etc and date_add date_sub

All of which are infinately better than the stupid built in php time/date functions etc where there's 90 million ways of doing things and none of them return the same results reliably.